# Start mysql with flag --local-infile using perl

Tags: mysql, perl, upload

I am writing a simple script to upload a list of files to tables in mysql using a perl program.
I normally can manually start mysql with the flag "--local-infile" whenever I need to upload a file.
I use perl as well to obtain information of tables in mysql database using DBI:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);
```

But I cannot figure out how to start mysql using perl with the flag required to upload files.
Is there a way to start the connection to mysql in perl already with the local enable?
Or maybe,
Is there a command that I could run in mysql to enable the upload files?
I should add that I am running on a remote host, so I have no editing access to my.cnf file
or root access in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host;mysql_local_infile=1", $user, $pass);
```

You can also pass other (local) variables in this manner. See [the documentation for DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.022/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#Class_Methods).

Answer (score 0):

First, add below code under *client* in my.cnf

**[client]**

loose-local-infile=1

Then add parameter;

```
mysql_local_infile=>1
```

below,

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass, {mysql_local_infile=>1, RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0, mysql_enable_utf8 => 1});
```

The other parameters belongs to my code but i put them for usage examples of **DBI->connect**.